# Is there a way to change the picture after CID is created in Pinata?

Tags: json, solidity, nft, opensea, pinata

everyone!!
Can i change the picture after minitng at Opensea?

Upload the image and json file to pinata.
And after minting on Opensea, can I change the image on pinata?
I want to change the image in Pinata so that it can be applied in Opensea.
I think i can change the image on own server, but is it possible on pinata?

Answer (score 1):

CID is a hash of the file contents. So if you change the contents, the CID changes as well.

---

Assuming that both image and metadata are on IPFS, there's a workaround:

1. Upload new image
2. Upload new metadata JSON that reflects the new image CID
3. Invoke a function in your contract that changes the URI of the token

If you don't have such function in your contract (and the contract is not upgradable), then it's not possible to perform any change to the NFT.